# Django-rest-framework drf-extensions: Nested routers/urls are not filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-extensions

I can't get the my Router to filter my requests based on the "parents_query_lookup".

Here's my code:

**urls.py:**

```
from rest_framework_extensions.routers import ExtendedSimpleRouter
from .views import OrganizationViewSet, GroupViewSet, BootGroupViewSet


router = ExtendedSimpleRouter()
(router.register(r'organizations', OrganizationViewSet,
                 base_name='organization')
    .register(r'groups', GroupViewSet,  base_name='organizations-group',
              parents_query_lookups=['resource__organization'])
    .register(r'boot_groups', BootGroupViewSet,
              base_name='organizations-groups-boot_group',
              parents_query_lookups=['group__resource__organization', 'group']))

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework_extensions.mixins import NestedViewSetMixin
from .models import Organization, OrganizationSerializer, \
    Group, GroupSerializer, BootGroup, BootGroupSerializer


class OrganizationViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer


class GroupViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer


class BootGroupViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BootGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BootGroupSerializer
```

**enums.py:**

```
class ResourceTypeEnum:

    RESOURCE_TYPE_GROUP = 'group'
    RESOURCE_TYPE_VM = 'vm'

    RESOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (RESOURCE_TYPE_GROUP, RESOURCE_TYPE_GROUP),
        (RESOURCE_TYPE_VM, RESOURCE_TYPE_VM)
    )
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db.models import Model
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from .enums import ResourceTypeEnum


class Organization(Model):
    organization_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "parent"))
        verbose_name = "Organization"
        verbose_name_plural = "Organizations"
        app_label = 'api_manager'
        db_table = 'organization'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class OrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('name', 'parent')
        depth = 2


class Resource(Model):
    resource_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=5, choices=ResourceTypeEnum.RESOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Resource"
        verbose_name_plural = "Resources"
        app_label = 'api_manager'
        db_table = 'resource'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class ResourceSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ('name', 'type', 'organization')
        depth = 2


class Group(Model):
    resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, primary_key=True)
    is_consistent = models.BooleanField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Group"
        verbose_name_plural = "Groups"
        app_label = 'api_manager'
        db_table = 'group'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.resource.organization, self.resource)


class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('resource', 'is_consistent', 'parent')
        depth = 2


class BootGroup(Model):
    boot_group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    boot_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("boot_order", "group"))
        verbose_name = "BootGroup"
        verbose_name_plural = "BootGroups"
        app_label = 'api_manager'
        db_table = 'boot_group'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.group.resource, self.name)


class BootGroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BootGroup
        fields = ('name', 'boot_order', 'group')
        depth = 2


class Vm(Model):
    resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, primary_key=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True)
    boot_group = models.ForeignKey(BootGroup, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Vm"
        verbose_name_plural = "Vms"
        app_label = 'api_manager'
        db_table = 'vm'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.resource.organization, self.resource)


class VmSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vm
        fields = ('resource', 'hostname', 'group',  'boot_group')
        depth = 2
```

No matter what I try, something like *"organizations/1/groups"* returns all of the **Group** models, regardless of **Organization**. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? If so please share

Answer (score 0):

Based on yours router definition, you need to define a queryset in `GroupViewSet`

```
from rest_framework_extensions.utils import compose_parent_pk_kwarg_name

 def get_queryset(self):
     resource_id =  self.kwargs.get(compose_parent_pk_kwarg_name('resource_organization')
     return Group.objects.filter(resource=resource_id)
```

The filter value can be find in kwargs as `parent_lookup_<parents_query_lookups>` or you can retrieve the parent query dict with `self.get_parents_query_dict()`